# How to import config file in quasar.conf.js and define environment contants

Tags: quasar-framework

Is it possible to import config file in quasar.conf.js?
I create some config file with env consts in src/config/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Answered by nothingismagick in Quasar Framework's Discord Channel.

## `/config/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: 'development',
  FOO: 'bar'
}
```

## `/src/pages/Index.vue`

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <div class="layout-view">
      API: {{ api }}
      <br>
      FOO: {{ bar }}
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PageIndex',
  data () {
    return {
      api: process.env.API,
      bar: process.env.FOO
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And your `quasar.conf.js`:

```
const config = require('./config/index.js')
...
module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    ...
    build: {
      env: ctx.dev
        ? { // so on dev we'll have
          API: JSON.stringify('https://dev.api.com'),
          FOO: JSON.stringify(config.FOO)
        }
        : { // and on build (production):
          API: JSON.stringify('https://prod.api.com')
        },
```

Comment: When answering questions, please explain what you are doing, either by comments in the code, or by text around the code.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I did the following:

`module.exports.foo = "bar"`

Now I could import foo in quasar.conf.js using this:

`const { foo } = require("./src/config/index");`